# GitHub Backtrack to Previous Push

Tags: github

I realize this isn't directly a coding question, but GitHub is widely used and I haven't seen how to do this, so I figured I'd ask as I'm trying to figure it out.

**Using GitHub how do I go about backtracking a development branch to a previous push point?**

For example, let's say I have a dev branch and I push faulty code, how do I backtrack to a previous point in that branch in the event I need to?

I'd prefer to see how to do this from the command line, but in the web UI is fine as well.

Comment: git and github questions are on topic, no problem. However, this question has been answered very thoroughly already, so you should please search before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your branch with the bad commit(s) has already been published to GitHub, and other users may have already pushed it, then you typically would *not* literally rollback that branch.  Instead, you would use `git revert` to functionally undo the bad commit:

```
git revert 1a7h3jxk       # where 1a7h3jxk is the SHA-1 hash of the bad commit
```

`git revert` actually adds a *new* commit which functionally undoes the commit you specify as a parameter.  It also allows syntax for specifying a range of commits.

If you really want to formally "backtrack" your branch, you *could* do a hard reset to remove the bad commit(s).  For example, to actually remove a single bad commit you could do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push --force origin your_branch
```

But note carefully that doing a hard reset means that you are rewriting the history of your branch.  This means you have to force push (read: overwrite) the version of the branch on the remote.  As mentioned above, this option should *not* be used if anyone shared this branch besides you.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, not sure how my initial search didn't provide me with these answers, but this works for what I was struggling to figure out, thanks! I marked this as duplicate because I didn't want to delete an answered question.